# Objectbox dart: How to filter objects within objects in ToOne Relation

Tags: flutter, dart, objectbox

Suppose I have code like this

```
@Entity()
class ObjectOne {
  int id;
  String code;
  String name;
  final objectTwo = ToOne<ObjectTwo>();
}

@Entity()
class ObjectTwo {
  int id;
  String code;
  String name;
  final objectThree = ToOne<ObjectThree>();
}

@Entity()
class ObjectThree {
  int id;
  String code;
  String name;
}
```

If you get the name value in the ObjectTwo class, you can use code like this

```
final objects = store.box<ObjectOne>().query()
  ..link(ObjectOne_.objectTwo, ObjectTwo_.name.equals("value"))
  ..build()
```

What if I want to retrieve the name value of class ObjectThree in class ObjectOne via class ObjectTwo ?

Thank youu...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add another link condition to the query builder returned by the first link condition:

```
    final builder = store.box<ObjectOne>().query();
    builder
        .link(ObjectOne_.objectTwo)
        .link(ObjectTwo_.objectThree, ObjectThree_.name.equals("value"));
    final query = builder.build();
```

[Source](https://github.com/objectbox/objectbox-dart/blob/04ad04a9856d4bdb3d6164f87ee54a08c7b17c28/objectbox/test/relations_test.dart#L146-L149)

Comment: wow it turns out to work using this method, thank you very much :D